# SQL Server Jobs - syspolicy_purge_history fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, jobs

The job `syspolicy_purge_history` fails at the 3rd step. The error that I get is the following one:

> Executed as user: UserABC. 
>    A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. 
>    The corresponding line is 'set-executionpolicy RemoteSigned -scope process  -Force'. 
>    Correct the script and reschedule the job. 
>    The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Security error.  '.   Process Exit Code -1.  The step failed.

Was wondering if you guys have faced this before and how to go about fixing this.

Comment: See https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/754063/sql-server-2012-syspolicy-purge-history-job-step-3-fails-with-security-error

Comment: See the very bottom of https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/bd3af3fb-cbaf-40cc-b3d6-4ab4d1614e9e/sql-server-2012-syspolicypurgehistory-fails-step-3-erase-phantom-system-health-records?forum=sqldatabaseengine.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of @Tony Hinkle.  I was able to resolve the issue based on the comment at the bottom of this thread.

[SQL Server 2012 syspolicy_purge_history fails step 3 "Erase Phantom System Health Records."](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/bd3af3fb-cbaf-40cc-b3d6-4ab4d1614e9e/sql-server-2012-syspolicypurgehistory-fails-step-3-erase-phantom-system-health-records?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps130` I changed the key `ExecutionPolicy` value to `Unrestricted`.

I did not make any changes to keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqltoolsps130`.